# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Data.IDbCommand'

Tags: c#, microsoft-sync-framework

Do you have an idea what might cause the error in the title? 
It highlights an error in the following part of the code:

```
        SyncAdapter notesSyncAdapter = notesBuilder.ToSyncAdapter();
        ((SqlParameter)notesSyncAdapter.SelectIncrementalInsertsCommand["@sync_last_received_anchor"]).DbType = System.Data.DbType.Binary;
        ((SqlParameter)notesSyncAdapter.SelectIncrementalInsertsCommand.Parameters["@sync_new_received_anchor"]).DbType = System.Data.DbType.Binary;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot a `.Parameters` after `SelectIncrementalInsertsCommand` on the second line.